# Bundle java jar stub data with react-native app to make it work offline

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I am working on an app which points to java jar for offline data, so whenever I launch the app on simulator, I need to start the stub data using java command to make it work, is there a way that I can bundle it with the app so that it works automatically in offline mode for both simulator and device.